# How to add/remove github dependancy with paket?

Tags: paket

The [docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-remove.html) say the command requires a package ID

My `paket.dependencies` looks like this:

```
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

nuget Xamarin.Essentials 1.0.1
nuget Xamarin.Forms 4.0.0.425677

github dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls
```

And I can successfully remove a nuget with `paket remove Xamarin.Essentials`, but `paket remove dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls` don't work

How can I remove a github dependancy with `paket remove`? And also, how can I use `paket add` to add a github dependancy - without manually editing the `paket.dependencies` file?

Comment: I see the same behaviour with `clitool` package type